# How to open current session Java Selenium?

Tags: java, session, selenium

I have seen many question, but could not implement any answer.

```
System.setProperty "webdriver.chrome.driver","chromedriverchromedriver.exe");

driver = new ChromeDriver();

// Then what exactly do I do?
//I want to open my regular Chrome window with all plugins and cookies
```

Comment: You cannot attach to an existing browser instance. You must create new instances and allow the WebDriver to control them from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver#Starting_Chromium_with_Specific_Flags:

> Or to load with a specific profile (note that the default profile
>   directories can be found here):
>
> ```
> DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
> capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--user-data-dir=/path/to/profile/directory"));
> WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
> ```